# Silent msi install command

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, silent

I have 10 .msi instalers in a folder.I want to install all one by one silently without giving the source path(Source may be anything like follows E:/MyInstallers or D:/Installers).
How to write a .bat file for the above action in windows7 and windows8?

Is it possible to give the installation path at installing time?

Comment: Just search for msiexec on this site there are quite few similar ones.

Comment: Thank you Preet Sangha. It works well for windows7 but can't work in windows8. And i want to know about Is it possible to give the installation path at installing time? in command prompt